# Python pip won't install from a private repo?

Tags: python, github, pip

I'm trying to install a repo from a private github repo using pip. When I use this command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/org/myrepo.git
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think so? My error is different and it prompts for my user and pass when I do this. I just enter my github token.

Comment: The error looks more like an error in the `setup.py`. Did you try to clone the repository manually and then do a `pip install .`?

Comment: I do not have a setup.py in that repo. do I do pip install . in the directory?

Comment: You can't install using `pip` without a `setup.py`... You need to write one if you want to use `pip`.

Comment: And if you don't own the repository, the easiest way is to clone the repository in some place safe and then update your `PYTHONPATH` accordingly.

Comment: well that would explain that. If you dont mind, could you explain some more about setup.py? If you can make it answer ill mark it.

Comment: I am far from on expert on setup scripts but the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) is pretty well-written.